# How to hide bash script output in terminal after closing script?

Tags: bash, shell

Now I know that the title doesn't really explain what I want to do, since I found similar things asked but none of them really covers what I want to do. There's probably is a name for what I'm trying to do but right now it eludes me.

So the easies way I can find of explaining what I'm trying to achieve is with examples. Right now I have an interactive bash script that works just as intended, but it bothers me that after closing it it stays on my terminal.
Think "top" vs "htop", after closing top you'll get a new prompt line but you'll still see the top output on your terminal. You can even scroll up the terminal after opening top.
With htop you can't really scroll up or down on the terminal, and when you close htop you'll only see the last prompt line calling htop.

So I'm trying to make my script run "contained", like htop or vi does, so I don't have to see the script output after closing it. Anyway to do this with bash?

Comment: That's a side effect of the initialization/deinitialization sequence used by full-screen applications, which switches to an alternate screen buffer.

Comment: The solution given by @rednep looks to me the most elegant. A simpler, but more brutal way, would be to call `clear` at the end of the script. However, this also erases the output which had been on your screen **before** your interactive tool has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput smcup
"$@"
tput rmcup
```

Call this `alt-screen.sh`. With the help of that script, you can run any other program in the so called alternate screen (which is where `htop` and `vi` run) as follows:

```
./alt-screen.sh foo --option=value arg1 arg2
```

For a concrete example, try this:

```
./alt-screen.sh bash -c 'date; sleep 3'
```

How does this work? It's very simple; it uses `tput` to switch to the alternate screen, it then executes the program and then it switches back to the original screen.

**Note**: The above script is rather simplistic. You may want to improve it in various ways. For example, the following version works as described above and also preserves the status code of the program:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput smcup
"$@"
status=$?
tput rmcup
exit $status
```

**Note 2**: I haven't tested this extensively, it will almost certainly have undesirable side-effects, but it might work just fine for many cases.